# Showing Database Search results in Datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with SQL Server 2012 for database in my Windows forms application c#.

I want to show my query search results in a `DataGridView`:

```
public void customerSearch(int custID, DataGridView dataGridView)
{
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Connection String");
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand searchQuery = new SqlCommand("select * from [Customer] where custId = @custID", connection);
            searchQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custId", custID);
            //searchQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = searchQuery.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    dataGridView.DataBindings.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Exception.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I got `NullReferenceException`  at `connection.Close();`
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Or any other method for this purpose ?

Comment: Actually i remove the connection string before posting. There is no issue with connection string as i gave it correctly @KhairulIslam

Comment: You should put your connection in your app.config instead of coding it in your form.

Comment: You also might want to take a look at this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: To actually look at your issue I am surprised this would compile. You have connection defined inside your try but in the finally you try to reference it. It is out of scope. You should instead wrap your connection in a USING.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry for that @JohnSaunders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put your connection in a USING it will automatically close and dispose your connection when the block exits.

```
public void customerSearch(int custID, DataGridView dataGridView)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {

                    connection.Open();

                    SqlCommand searchQuery = new SqlCommand("select * from [Customer] where custId = @custID", connection);
                    searchQuery.Parameters.Add("@custId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = custID;
                    //searchQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = searchQuery.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        dt.Load(reader);
                        dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                        dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
                        dataGridView.Refresh();
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Exception.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

--EDIT--

You can't bind a DataGridView to a DataReader. I edited the code above to demonstrate one way to do this. I just create a DataTable from your reader and bind the grid to the DataTable.

Comment: Not sure what you doing with the DataBindings.ToString to be honest. Are you trying to bind the grid to the reader?

Comment: Yes a kind of . Actually I want to show my query result in 'DataGridView'.

Comment: OK. I understand now what you want. I edited the code to demonstrate one way of doing that.

Comment: perfectly explained, really solved my issue... thanks