# Creating Search Function using Vb.Net in Visual Studio and SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, visual-studio

I am looking for help for creating a function to sort a database I have on a SQL Server in which I can search for name and part number. I have my database connected to visual studio but struggling to connect to database within code and being able to generate the database on the data grid view.

Anything helps, thanks

Comment: Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30538342/12666543

Comment: @XingyuZhao This is a vb.net question.

Comment: What does this have to do with Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of concepts you'll need to implement:

1. Connect to the database
2. Setup your SQL command with the necessary `WHERE` clause
3. Fill a DataTable with the results
4. Bind the DataTable to the DataGridView

Here is an example, I've heavily commented the code to explain what is going on:

```vb
' wrap code in Try/Catch because database operations can fail
Try
    ' create a new instance of the connection object
    Using connection = New SqlConnection("My Connection String Here")

        ' create a new instance of the command object
        Using command = New SqlCommand("Select * From MyTable WHERE Name = @name AND PartNumber = @part", connection)
            ' parameterize the query
            command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "my name search"
            command.Parameters.Add("@part", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "my part number search"

            ' open the connection
            connection.Open()

            ' create a new instance of the data adapter object
            Using adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                ' fill a DataTable with the data from the adapter
                Dim table = New DataTable()
                adapter.Fill(table)

                ' bind the DataTable to the DataGridView
                MyDataGridView.DataSource = table
            End Using

            ' close the connection
            connection.Close()
        End Using ' disposal of command
    End Using ' disposal of connection
Catch ex As Exception
    ' display the error
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: @PasskyyCode Note correct use of `Using` to dispose all objects, correct use of parameterization, specifying the parameter type and length, opening the connection as late as possible, and catching and displaying exceptions *after* closing the connection. You should generally avoid `SELECT *` and instead specify all columns you want

Comment: You don't have to call connection.Open() / connection.Close() when using the adapter.Fill method. It automatically does these for you.